# ColumnHeader.Name yields an empty string at runtime

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Using the *ListView* control in Winforms projects (Visual Studio 2010), I've noticed that although I have assigned meaningful values to the *Name* property of its ColumnHeaders in the column designer, calling `columnHeaderFoo.Name` returns an empty string at runtime. This differs from the behavior of other controls, e.g. on the same form, `buttonOK.Name` yields `"buttonOK"`.

Here's where I set the value:

[image: Using the column designer to set the column name]

Alternatively here, with the same result:

[image: Using the property editor to set the column name]

This is the designer-generated code for a form with a ListView containing one column:

```
namespace ColumnDemo
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.columnHeaderTest = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this.columnHeaderTest});
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(494, 149);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(411, 167);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 43);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(518, 221);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeaderTest;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

I add some output on button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Button: " + button1.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Column: " + columnHeaderTest.Name);
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
Button: button1 
Column:
```

Another interesting fact is that none of the project's files contain the value I gave as "Name" anywhere in the form of a string constant; it seems VS uses this value exclusively to name the member variable.

If I set the *Name* property as runtime, the value is retained as expected. It seems I always just wrongly assumed that the forms designer uses the field labeled "Name" to assign the *Name* property.

Is there any way to unambiguously define a control's name (not the name of the variable) at design time?

Comment: share your code... !!!

Comment: I use the Visual Studio designer for ListView-ColumnHeaders to set the name (no code), then use `columnHeaderFoo.Name` to try to read it out.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild the project ... once and try it...

Comment: @AravindSrinivas This is reproducible even in fresh projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225001/net-listview-column-order-problem  .. please see this ... and see the answers...they are facing same problem

Comment: @AravindSrinivas Thanks, I've had a look, but this seems to be a different problem. It seems that neither the designer-generated code nor the resource files contain the string I'd like as a name; see my edits.

Comment: Where you are setting the name of the ColumnHeader this.columnHeaderTest.Name = "Test";

Comment: @AravindSrinivas Please see the new screenshots

Comment: Hey that name is different and this name is different Once if you are changing the name then ColumnName will be changed ... like i will update my answer go through it

Comment: did  you saw that ? ... it works fine for me....

Comment: I think after i updated my answer you visited more than 3 to 4 times this page, but didn't made any reply for my answer...are you facing any other problem ?

Answer (score 0):

where you are setting this

```
 this.button1.Name = "button1"; // This value is Set !!!!!
  this.columnHeaderTest.Name ----> this value is not set that's why you are getting empty.
this.columnHeaderTest.Name = "Test";
```

when i sett this i am getting the value correctly ...

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button: " + button1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Column: " + columnHeaderTest.Name);
    }
columnHeaderTest.Name
"Test"


 as you showed in screenshot . just change the " columnHeaderTest to Testing " .... this is 
 Control Name ... you have define your controls Display name that is 

 Testing.Name = "NewColumn";
```

then you will get the name ....  ... check this

Comment: You are correct, when I set the value in the code it is retained. My question is why doesn't this work when I set it in the designer (maybe this is by design, maybe I'm using it wrong)?

Comment: Waldrumpus ... ListView is Control and Columheader is another control inside it .. when you are creating new columnheader it wont create ColumnHeader name it will just create a control inside list view so that you wont get anything in name property for that only i said you have to set the name manually ... This is default design of  Listview columnheader